# How to control a capacitive load using an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, analog, driver

I'm trying to control a liquid lens using an Arduino Uno, however, the [lens driver](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/HV892%20A042314.pdf) I've been attempting to get hold of is no longer an option.

The lens needs up to 60Vrms in order to function, and will likely be overdriven in order to minimise the response time. I'm looking into using a DC/DC boost converter feeding into an H-bridge but am unsure whether it would work and seeking advice.

Is there a solution whereby I can control the lens by outputting a PWM signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the liquid lenses seem to require a fixed frequency, variable amplitude AC waveform without any DC bias at a rather low frequency spectrum (<20 kHz). Not only that, but they have a very high impedance (less than a nanofarad).

The commercial application specific chips use a complex topology with a charge pump boosting the voltage and a H-bridge acting as an inverter. This allows them to be very compact, efficient and cheap to mass produce.

I see no reason why you would want to replicate this with boost converters, high voltage H bridges and the like. You could use a DAC and a low power amplifier to directly drive a step up transformer, which requires only easily available cheap parts: a single channel serial DAC such as the 12-bit [MCP4821](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22244B.pdf), A low power linear mono audio amplifier such as the [tpa4861](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa4861.pdf) and a hand wound transformer on a toroidal ferrite core with a turn ratio about 30:1.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After the DAC takes my input and outputs a voltage between Vdd and 0V, aren't I meant to turn that into an AC signal in order for the audio amplifier to function?

Comment: You start with a digital representation of the waveform in the arduino RAM: An array of numeric vales, each of which corresponds to an output voltage at a point in time. You synthesise the waveform *with* the DAC (by rapidly updating the value), and its output *is* the analog signal. The DAC output is not suitable for driving a transformer directly, so you amplify the DAC output first.

Comment: You want capacitive coupling between the DAC and amp to block any DC voltage offset, a 100nF capacitor between the two would work. This should get you started on how to digitally synthesise the waveform: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=130751.0

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, according the output waveform diagram in the datasheet, the output is **not PWM**, but instead a ~1.5kHz square wave with variable amplitude and controlled edge rates. Simply feeding PWM from the Arduino to an H-bridge doesn't appear to be sufficient.

Rather, you need to create a dynamically variable voltage supply and power the H-bridge from that. The H-bridge is driven with a constant frequency square wave and the supply voltage is varied.

First off, the DC/DC: 62Vrms is ~88Vpk. So you need a ~90V boost converter. This shouldn't be too difficult, but requires some careful design. A part such as Linear's LT8331 or similar should work.

Now that you've got an HV supply, you need to figure out how to modulate it. It doesn't sound like you need *really* fast response time, so it might be feasible to PWM it, and filter that to get a stable supply voltage (you are basically designing a unipolar class-D amplifier). The datasheet specifies a response time of 20ms for 0% to 90%, so you might have enough separation between modulation rate and PWM frequency to make this work. On an Arduino, you'll need to ditch the built-in libraries and configure the hardware PWM to go as fast as possible (~65kHz IIRC).

Alternatively, you *could* try using a boost converter with dynamic feedback. However, this wouldn't work with voltages below 5V (I don't know if that's important). A SEPIC architecture might work as well, but I'm not sure how close to 0V it could get.